Change Woocommerce download_url for guest users and checkouts
The problem I am trying to solve is how to change the download_url for guest users at the order-received wc_endpoint_url.
My goal is to be able to put guest user downloads on the same domain behind a location that can in turn be excluded from the page cache. Similar to what is done here with my-account/downloads, except for guest users.
This is following up on another thread that has been helpful in getting this far. The recommended solution in that thread works well for logged in users and does indeed update the URL to /account/downloads/.
The download links available during the order-received stage by default use the site's root URL and then the /?download_file string.
I have tried several iterations using some of the available Woocommerce filters and search for "download", but can't get a working implementation.
The part I'm struggling with is order-received and whether it can be called through wc_endpoint_url similiar to the original post that inspired this approach.
Here are some examples of what I have tried so far.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 'filter_woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 10, 2 );

function filter_woocommerce_customer_available_downloads( $downloads, $customer_id ) {
    // Only on my account downloads section
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) )
        return $downloads;

    // Loop though downloads
    foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
        // Replace
        $downloads[$key]['download_url'] = str_replace( '/?download_file', '/account/downloads/?download_file', $download['download_url'] );
    }

    return $downloads;
}


// Filter Guest Download links
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_downloads', 'modify_available_downloads_for_guests', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Function for `woocommerce_available_downloads` action-hook.
 * 
 * @param  $downloads 
 *
 * @return void
 */
function modify_available_downloads_for_guests( $downloads, $order ) {
    // Apply this only to the "order-received" page
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        return $downloads;
    }

    // Modify each download's URL
    foreach ( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
        $downloads[$key]['download_url'] = str_replace( '/?download_file', '/account/downloads/?download_file', $download['download_url'] );
    }

    return $downloads;
}

